# Как пользоваться Google Maps, размещенный непосредственно на сайте?

Tags: javascript, html, html5, frontend

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Суть проблемы: Разрабатываю сайт, одной из компонент которых является Google Maps. Его можно перемещать и смотреть на местность. И Всё! Но мне нужно, чтобы я мог отмечать точки, это нужно для вычисления кратчайшего пути,начиная от старта ракеты до ее приземления используя GPS, показать направление,вычислить широту и долготу (У Google Maps есть такие функции). А проблема в том, чтобы это сделать надо перейти на сайт этой карты через "View larger map". А надо прямо на сайте, не переходя на "большую карту". Это возможно?

```
<iframe width="360" height="237" margin="auto" id="gmap_canvas" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?width=360&amp;height=237&amp;margin=auto&amp;hl=en&amp;q=Adil%20Mammadov%20Baku+(MSU-Space)&amp;t=k&amp;z=15&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;iwloc=B&amp;output=embed" style="height: 260px;margin: auto;border-radius: 5px;border: 0;"></iframe>
```

Есть идеи?

Comment: открывать большую карту в ифрейме же =)

Comment: @Инквизитор впринципе идея хоршая мне кажется. Есть ссылка, где это подробнее написано? Ну или как это реализовать?

Comment: тут: webref.ru/html/iframe